# Understanding IIFE's

Tags: javascript

I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression" (IIFE's).

I'm trying to design a game (I have a working model right now, but it's not object oriented and my goal is to better design and implement code), and I was told to not make my object references global.

Here's what I have right now.

```
var engine = new _engine();
engine.count++; //there's a lot more to the engine, I just haven't converted it yet
```

Here's what I tried:

```
(function() { var engine = new _engine(); }());
engine.count++; //error, engine is not defined
```

So now I'm trying this, and it works, but I'm scared it might still be global!

```
var engine = (function(){ return new _engine(); }());
engine.count++; //works, but is this still global?
```

Object design in JavaScript is a very new concept to me, so I want to make absolutely sure I'm learning the right way to do this, along with understand WHY this is working.

Please note that I need to be able to access the engine from wherever in the page. Does that make the need for a global? Why are globals so frowned upon? (Other objects reference the engine based on function returns and boolean variables)

Comment: IIFE has nothing specifically to do with object oriented programming. People mostly use it because JavaScript doesn't have any sort of package or module system, so they need to invoke a function so that they don't end up creating a bunch of global variables. Also they get used to emulate block scope. From your simple example, I'd say there's no reason to use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of an acceptable design for what you are trying to achieve. At the end your application will have a single entry point and use a single global variable which is used as your application's namespace.

You can and probably should make use of dependency injection at construction time (or using an injector) to inject dependencies into objects rather than relying on external well-known variables.

**If you are really serious about writing modular code, have a look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).**

*Engine.js*

```
(function (ns) {
    function Engine() {
    }

    Engine.prototype.someMethod = function () {
    };

    ns.Engine = Engine;
})(window.myNamespace = window.myNamespace || {});
```

*Game.js*

```
(function (ns) {
    function Game(engine) {
        this._engine = engine;
    }

    Game.prototype.start = function () {
        this._engine.someMethod();
    };

    ns.Game = Game;
})(window.myNamespace = window.myNamespace || {});
```

*app.js*

```
//kickstart your app
(function () {
    var engine = new myNamespace.Engine(),

        //init the Game while injecting the engine dependency
        game = new myNamespace.Game(engine);

    game.start();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the following:

```
(function() {
    var engine = new _engine();
    engine.count++;
    // all other code depending on engine should be in here as well
})();
```

Your code will do the exact same thing as your original version, but now `engine` is local to the IIFE instead of being global.

**edit:** After the discussion in comments, it sounds like you really do need `engine` to be global.  In this case you are probably fine leaving your code the way it is, but to make sure you aren't exposing any other variables as globals besides `engine` you could do something like the following:

```
var engine = (function() {
   var engine = new _engine();
   engine.count++;
   // any other code from your engine file (probably the _engine definition, etc)

   return engine;  // return local engine from the IIFE
})();
```

Or alternatively (this is what jQuery and some other popular libraries use):

```
(function(window) {
   var engine = new _engine();
   engine.count++;
   // any other code from your engine file (probably the _engine definition, etc)

   window.engine = engine;  // assign engine to window.engine to make it global
})(window);
```

Comment: But if I need to execute different engine functions and variables in different places, how can I do that? I only want to use `new _engine()` once, and be able to reference it where I need to.

Comment: Either put all of that code into the IIFE as well, or just leave your code the way it is in your first block.

Comment: Would that be a good design though? I was told globals are bad practice

Comment: Yep, it would probably be preferable to put everything into the IIFE.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, other objects will need to point to the engine object and I can't throw all that into one IIFE I'm assuming.

Comment: Assuming all of your code is in a single file, you can almost definitely just add `(function() {` before all of your code and `})();` after it.  Everything will likely work the same way, with no pollution of the global namespace.

Comment: Ahh, but I will have separate files for each object D:

Comment: @F.J Polluting the global namespace is never necessary. You can achieve what the OP's trying to do by namespacing objects and using dependency injection.